# Setting a goal point where is an obstacle

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any parameter to allow setting a goal where is an obstacle, which transform this goal point, where is an obstacle, into other goal point near the previous one obstacle free.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374178/setting-a-goal-point-where-is-an-obstacle/) by [DaveH](https://answers.ros.org/users/72087/daveh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know of at least two existing packages that could provide the functionality that you want :

- [Carrot Planner](http://wiki.ros.org/carrot_planner)
- [asr_navfn](http://wiki.ros.org/asr_navfn)

---

[Carrot Planner](http://wiki.ros.org/carrot_planner) will move your robot straight to the goal position and stop it in front of any obstacle.

I quote from their wiki page:

> The planner takes a goal point from an
> external user, checks if the
> user-specified goal is in an obstacle,
> and if it is, it walks back along the
> vector between the user-specified goal
> and the robot until a goal point that
> is not in an obstacle is found. It
> then passes this goal point on as a
> plan to a local planner or controller.
> In this way, the carrot planner allows
> the robot to get as close to a
> user-specified goal point as possible.

To test it you just have to add the following code to the launch file where you start move_base:

```
<param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner" />
```

This is an exemplary launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <!-- Start move_base (nav stack) node and load config files -->    
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find your_pkg)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find your_pkg)/config/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find your_pkg)/config/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find your_pkg)/config/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find your_pkg)/config/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  
    <!-- Set the global planner: -->
    <param name="base_global_planner" value="carrot_planner/CarrotPlanner" /> 

  </node>

</launch>
```

---

The second option I know, the [asr_navfn package](http://wiki.ros.org/asr_navfn), is also a global planner that can navigate your robot to the closest free space if the desired destination is in an obstacle. The main benefit is that it is not limited to a stright line path, as in [Carrot Planner](http://wiki.ros.org/carrot_planner).

The image on their wiki page is pretty self-explanatory:

[image: image description]

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) with karma: 500 on 2021-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DaveH](https://answers.ros.org/users/72087/daveh/) on 2021-03-18**:
The asr_navfn package is exactly what I have been looking for, thanks.

**Comment by [Roberto Z.](https://answers.ros.org/users/39640/roberto-z./) on 2021-03-18**:
I am glad that this resolved your question.